# Json and ASP.NET MVC Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have a UI that looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to data of the newly created row to the server so that the server may save it.

I am sending data in JSON format from the client to my MVC application. Here's my ajax request:

```
var values = []; // an array with each item being an object/associative array

// more code to get values into variables

for (var i = 0; i < cultures.length; i++) {
  var cultureName = cultures[i];
  var valueTextBox = $(row).find(...);
  var value = $(valueTextBox).val();

  var cultureNameAndValue = { 'CultureShortName' : cultureName, 'StringValue' : value };

  values.push(cultureNameAndValue);
}

var stringTableRow = 
  { 
    'ResourceKeyId': resourceKeyId, 
    'Key': resourceKeyName, 
    'CategoryId': categoryId, 
    'CategoryName': categoryName, 
    'StringValues': values 
  };

var stringified = JSON.stringify({ StringTableRow: stringTableRow });

$.ajax('/Strings/JsonCreateNew', 
      { 
        cache: false, 
        async: false, 
        type: 'POST', 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
        data: stringified, 
        dataType: 'json', 
        error: SaveNewResourceClientSideHandler.OnError, 
        success: SaveNewResourceClientSideHandler.OnSuccess 
      });
```

Here's the data it sends (as seen in Firebug):

```
{"StringTableRow":{"ResourceKeyId":"","Key":"Foo",
"CategoryId":"1","CategoryName":"JavaScript",
"StringValues":[
{"CultureShortName":"en-US","StringValue":"Something"},
{"CultureShortName":"fr-FR","StringValue":""}]
}}
```

Here's my server side code:

```
public ActionResult JsonCreateNew(StringTableRow row)
{
  // CreateNewStringTableRow(row);

  // return a success code, new resource key id, new category id
  // return Json(
              new { Success = true, ResourceKeyId = row.ResourceKeyId, 
                    CategoryId = row.CategoryId }, 
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

  return new EmptyResult();
}
```

And here's the business object that I want my incoming POST'ed data to be bound to:

```
public class StringTableRow
{
    public StringTableRow()
    {
        StringValues = new List<CultureNameAndStringValue>();
    }

    public long ResourceKeyId { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public long CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public IList<CultureNameAndStringValue> StringValues { get; set; }  
}


public class CultureNameAndStringValue
{
  public string CultureShortName { get; set; }

  public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
        }
    }
```

Problem:

The action `JsonCreateNew` receives an object that is not null but has all properties uninitialized, i.e all nullable properties are null and value properties are at their default values. Therefore, effectively I get no data at all even when the client sends a perfectly valid Json string.

Do I need to do custom model binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved my problem and this might be an important insight for other programmers as well, because I learnt something while solving my own problem.

**My solution:**
I resorted to not using JSON and instead used the default encoding that HTTP uses for encoding form posted values, and then I used something that smacks of custom model binding (without actually creating a model binder).

**Explanation:**
Normally, when you make an ajax request and pass data from the client to any server platform, if you do not specify the encoding, i.e. the `contentType` parameter in the settings object of jQuery's ajax method (or if you are using any other means to make the ajax request other than jQuery, then however that thing sets the `ContentType` HTTP header is what you're after), HTTP encodes your posted data using its default encoding, which is much like what you post with a GET request after the query string, only it is binary encoded and not sent as a part of the URL.

If that's the case, and you're posting a collection of any type (`IList`, `IEnumerable`, `ICollection`, `IDictionary`, etc.) to ASP.NET MVC, then don't create an associative array in JavaScript to embody the collection. Don't even create an array. Don't create anything.

In fact, just pass it along inside the main big object using the convention:

```
data = 
{ /*scalar property */ Gar: 'har', 
  /* collection */ 'Foo[index++].Bar' : 'value1', 
  'Foo[index++].Bar' : 'value2'
}
```

And don't use JSON. That will solve half your problem.

On the server side, receive the posted data in a `FormCollection` and use its `IValueProvider` methods (`GetValue`) to dig out the data you need. You don't have to explicitly create a model binder to do it. You can do it in a private method of your controller itself.

I will improve this answer a bit later when I can find more time.

Comment: I am also in a similiar scenario, when i post data to server using ajax request , then i have to bind all the form values to json format like                var name = $("Name").val();
            var age = $("Age").val();
            // build json object
            var squirrel = {
               Name: name,
               Age: age,
            
           };
 Is there anyother way by which i don't have to manually bind values to json.Means is there anything which can directly convert my viewmodel to json and then i can get it in controller as an object?

Answer (score -3):

Use Backbone or KnockoutJs for data binding.

Comment: Thanks, Tarun. I had kept knockout as the last resort. I just did not want to delegate my problem to an abstraction because I would then lose control. I am building the UI in jQuery because I had just walked away from using DevExpress controls, another abstraction. I knew that problem was to do with custom model binding and didn't want to fall back on an abstraction like knockout (unless I had no other choice). I have solved my problem and will post the solution soon.